# rCharts not displaying when saving as webpage from RStudio

Tags: rcharts

I am building a presentation in rStudio using rCharts. The charts display in the RStudio preview window and I am able to interact with them. However, when I view it in any browser, or save it as a webpage, the charts completely disappear. When I inspect the elements in the webpage, there does not seem to be any javascript associated with the charts, which leads me to believe the problem is with Java. I have the latest version of both R and Java (32 bit) installed so I am not really sure what the issue could be. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if I can provide any additional info.

Thank you.

Edit: I get the following errors when loading the page:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined KPI2.html:967

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined KPI2.html:1106

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined KPI2.html:126

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined KPI2.html:1432

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined KPI2.html:1571

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. For some reason "http" was being dropped from the file paths. I went into the markdown file and edited it with notepad and that did the trick. It was driving me crazy. Hopefully this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

In the .md file of your R presentation, change

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js></script>
```

to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js></script>
```